# How do I share File-Link with Google Drive File Stream?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace

I wonder if it is possible to right click on a file in my Drive File Stream to get a shareable link to the file, like in Google Drive, Dropbox, OneDrive etc.?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for  https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for your input. 
I did not know that there is that communiy. I am sorry.